# Avoid reload when activating browser

Tags: browser

When I start my mobile browser it is usually to browse some other place than what it currently shows, but both firefox and the default browser insist on reloading what random page they hold before I'm able to proceed.

Is there any way to avoid the reload in these browsers?

**Edit**

The answer from *NDgeek* works as a workaround for the default browser, but not for Firefox as it requires at least one tab to exist.

After poking around a bit with the two applications, a similar workaround occurred to me, which is to point the active tab to a light-weight page before exiting, e.g. `about:blank` or `about:home`, now when the browser is activated it is available quicker.

I'll use the above workaround but as it requires extra work from me before I move away from the browser, I would prefer a more automatic solution.

Comment: I just ignore the reload and go right to the bookmark or entry of the URL I want to visit.    There's no need to wait for the reload to complete, at least with the stock Gingerbread browser.

Comment: On my Nexus S with Android 4.1.1 it doesn't respond before at least part of the reload completes.

Answer (score 1):

The only way I know of to prevent this when opening the browser directly is to close all tabs before exiting the browser. If you open a link from another app, you should be able to avoid this as well.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Closing all tabs works to some extent, see the added an edit to the question. Opening links from other apps is not an issue, its only when manually opening the browser.